# Removing class change list size

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a project and I found something that I don't understand.

I'm removing class from element to simulate selection/deselection.

However when I remove a class to an element. this element disapears from the list where it was. And so the list size changes.

why does the element disapears from the list ?
Is there a event sent to force the calculation?

**Javascript & HTML FILE**

```js
window.onload = function() {


  var listes = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
  var output = document.getElementsByClassName("output");


  for (var i = 0; i < listes.length; i++) {
    //not part of the problem ,just to show the output for the snippet
    output[0].innerHTML = output[0].innerHTML + 'list size ' + listes.length + '<br>';

    listes[i].classList.remove("test");

  }


}
```

```html
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<br>

<div class="output">output :
  <br>
</div>
```

**Output**

as Output I got:
list size 4 
list size 3 

*not keeping iterating because the i became equal to the list size*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list[i]` is probably not the element you want to remove as on each iteration the list changes so in fact you would want to remove the new first element.

You also need to store the initial value of `listes.length`

```
  var listes = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
  var listes_length = listes.length;
  var output = document.getElementsByClassName("output");


  for (var i = 0; i < listes_length; i++) {
    //not part of the problem ,just to show the output for the snippet
    output[0].innerHTML = output[0].innerHTML + 'list size ' + listes.length + '<br>';

    listes[0].classList.remove("test");

  }
```

Edit: As suggested above you probably want to use an `Array`

```
  var listes = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
  var alistes = Array.prototype.slice.call(listes, 0);
  var output = document.getElementsByClassName("output");


  for (var i = 0; i < alistes.length; i++) {
    //not part of the problem ,just to show the output for the snippet
    output[0].innerHTML = output[0].innerHTML + 'list size ' + listes.length + '<br>';

    alistes[i].classList.remove("test");

  }
```

Comment: Code 1:i did it with a while for your solution works too.
Code 2: I don't understand why my list changes and not the Array ... 
what is the process behind?

Comment: That is the way `NodeList`  is specified. It is a live collection as opposed to an `Array` and `document.getElementsByClassName("test")` returns a `NodeList`

Answer (score 0):

Your listes is not an array, but a DOM nodeList!

Make an array copy of it, like this:

```
alistes = Array.prototype.slice.call(listes, 0);
```

This alistes won't shrink when removing class from listes elements.

Comment: ty for the answer.
however I dont understand why this list is recalculated after the remove of a class

Comment: Again: listes is _not_ an array, but a DOM nodeList. It _is_ following DOM changes according to its definition. That's why you need to clone it into ay _array_ that remains unchanged until you change it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting what you are aiming for but,i've tried this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<br>
<div class="output">output :
    <br>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var listes = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    var output = document.getElementsByClassName("output");
    for (var i = 0; i < listes.length; i++) {
        //not part of the problem ,just to show the output for the snippet
        output[0].innerHTML = output[0].innerHTML + 'list size ' + listes.length + '<br>';

        listes[i].classList.remove(".test");
    }

    });
```

Working fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/886d86t1/1/

Comment: indeed it's working on Jsfiddle... even when I use ('No Library')